# Taking multiple inputs with different names in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input

I want enter multiple input like `number 1,` `number 2`, `number 3`, number n. But this should not be like writing all of them one by one, it is possible to try

```
a,b= map(input().split())
```

or

```
for i in xrange(1, 10):
    num.append(raw_input('Enter the %s number: '))
```

but it should take variable names like `number1, a,b` etc to make comparision with if so on.

```
number1 = int ( input ( "Enter number 1 " ) )
number2 = int ( input ( "Enter number 2 " ) )


if number1 < number2:
    print ( 'number1 ({}) is less number2 ({})'.format ( number1, number2 ) )
elif number1 == number2:
    print ( 'number1 ({}) is equal to number2 ({})'.format ( number1, number2 ) )
elif number1 >= number2:
    print ( "number 1 ({}) is greater or equal to number 2 ({})".format ( number1, number2 ) )
else:
    print (
        'number1 ({}) is not less than number2 ({})'.format ( number1, number2 ) )
```

Comment: Just use a list instead of numbered variables. Or unpack from a list yourself manually. Programmatic variable names are a bad anti-pattern.

Comment: What's wrong about `num[0] < num[1]`instead of `number1 < number2`?

Comment: Thanks, I used as your suggestion. num[0] < num[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a dictionary for a variable number of variables.

For example:

```
d = {}

for i in range(10):
    d.update({i: int(input('Enter number {}:'.format(i)))})
```

Then perform comparisons between your dictionary elements which, conveniently, have unique keys for you to access.

Also note that `xrange` / `raw_input` is used in Python 2.x. In Python 3.x, which is how you have tagged the question, use `range` / `input`.

Comment: Thanks for inspiration :This was what I need.

number = {}

for i in range(2):
    number.update({i: int(input('Enter number {}:'.format(i)))})

if number[0] < number[1]:
    print ( 'number[0] ({}) is less number[1] ({})'.format ( number[0]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
numbers = []

for i in range(10):
    n = int(input('Enter number {}:'.format(i))
    numbers.append(n)
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution with your valuable help.

Comment: Cool, if it helped please mark it as correct if it helped :)